# Unable to update back the state of DB column after interval using sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sidekiq

I have tried for sometime to get delayed_for to work in my controller code so i can change the state of the DB column from "locked" = true to "locked" = false after an interval period of time using sidekiq in my controller.

I know delayed_for is for compatibility method for delayed_job gem and if there is anyway i can do this, it would certainly be helpful.

**code:**

```
  def choose_number
    @stocks = NumberStock.offset(rand(NumberStock.count)).first(5)
    @stocks.each do |stock|
      stock.locked = true
      stock.save
    end
    @stocks.each do |stock|
      stock.delay_for(20.seconds).locked = false
      stock.delay_for(30.seconds).save
    end
    @simcard = Simcard.find(params[:id])
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the update and save all in one step:

```
@stocks.each do |stock|
  NumberStock.delay_for(30.seconds).update(stock.id, locked: false)
end
```

The jobs will do into the *default* queue, so also make sure that your workers are configured to process the *default* queue in your `sidekiq.yml`. For example:

```
---
:concurrency: 5
:queues:
  - [high, 10]
  - [low, 3]
  - [default, 1]
```

Comment: tried the following code but it does not update the column, "locked" to be false. I needed a way to set the table row so it will not be picked up by the query in a specified interval. (for example, the user has a few options for 30 seconds)

Comment: What happens? Does the job fail? Stay queued forever? Seems to run, but doesn't update the record?

Comment: Yes. the job seems to run but doesn't update the record.

Comment: Here's the debug info the sidekiq:

2014-08-13T03:08:09.229Z 5703 TID-7hs DEBUG: enqueued schedule: {"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel","args":["---\n- !ruby/object:NumberStock\n  attributes:\n    id: 430994\n    msisdn: '01122550623'\n    iccid: '89601613100301093148'\n    created_at:\n    updated_at: 2014-08-13 03:06:58.948000000 Z\n    locked: true\n    selected:\n- :update\n- - :locked: false\n"],"jid":"b621653a23fabbaf43577336","enqueued_at":1407899219.044}

Comment: Do these jobs get stuck in enqueued state and never run or do they run without errors? The jobs will go into the 'default' queue, so if you don't have a default listed in your queues in sidekiq.yml they will never get run.

Comment: It says done. 
2014-08-13T04:13:50.442Z 8786 TID-7as DEBUG: enqueued schedule: {"retry":true,"queue":"default","class":"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel","args":["---\n- !ruby/object:NumberStock\n  attributes:\n    id: 35835\n    msisdn: 01122538329\n    iccid: '89601613100300978356'\n    created_at:\n    updated_at: 2014-08-13 04:12:47.445000000 Z\n    locked: true\n    selected: false\n- :update\n- - :locked: 'false'\n"],"jid":"e0d4e76710ae6ad7eb5d74f0","enqueued_at":140790316
TID-7be Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedModel JID-e0d4e76710ae6ad7eb5d74f0 INFO: done: 0.193 sec

Comment: question. Why is when we use the update method, it instead uses ':locked:' instead of 'locked:' ?

Comment: Because it is getting serialized to YAML as a symbol rather than a string.

Comment: In sidekiq web interface, it shows that the jobs did not get stuck in enqueued state and the jobs ran without errors as above. I never did use sidekiq.yml but even when i ran 'bundle exec sidekiq -v' - it goes to the 'default' queue. Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure then, I've tested this and works fine for me under Sidekiq 3.2.2.

Comment: I have tried your edited code and it works like a charm right now. Thank you.